# How to separate first and last names with multiple lines from textarea into array

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have two input fields asking for guest first and guest last name.  When the user clicks "Add", those two values are being temporarily stored into a textarea and appended (in jquery) so they can add however many they want.

```
<input id="guest_first" type="text" name="guest_first" placeholder="Guest First Name" class="form-control"/>

<input id="guest_last" type="text" name="guest_last" placeholder="Guest Last Name" class="form-control"/>

<textarea id="guest_storage" name="guest_storage" class="form-control"></textarea>
```

JQUERY:

```
$('#guest_storage').append(
      $('#guest_first').val() + ' ' + $('#guest_last').val() + '\r\n');
```

When entering Jane in the guest_first box and Doe in the guest_last and so on, I get the following in the textarea as expected.

```
Jane Doe
John Doe
Ehye Sukk
```

I have a mysql table which contains "guest_first" and "guest_last".  I'm trying to get these into an array to read and insert into the db so each record will contain first and last. This is where I am lost.

I am assuming I'd have to do an explode looking for the space between to determine which is first and last name as separate arrays but also an explode on the \r\n to make each their own array?  I am thinking:

```
$guests = $_POST['guest_storage'];

$guests = explode(" ", $guests); 

foreach($guests as $key=>$guest) {

  foreach(explode("\r\n", $guest) as $value) { //or preg_split('/\r\n|[\r\n]/', $guests);
  ...NOT SURE WHAT WOULD BE DONE HERE
  }
}
```

This would be my insert statement:

```
$guest_query = "INSERT INTO registration (guest_first, guest_last) VALUES ('$guest_first', '$guest_last')";

$guest_data = mysqli_query($dbConnect, $guest_query);
```

Am I over-complicating this?

Comment: Of course this does not contain SQL injection prevention, nor did I account for spaces in between last names and or middle names, I can worry about that later.  Thanks

Comment: Short answer: First split/explode by line break, then by space (not the other way around as you try to do). Long answer: It depends on what you are going to do, if someone types in double names like "Joana Maria" as `guest_first` and "Garcia Sanchez" as `guest_last`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PHP_EOL` in `explode` function to separate full names.

```
<?php
// Let's suppose your textarea has posted these names
$names = 'Jane Doe
John Doe
Ehye Sukk';
// Using PHP_EOL
$names = explode(PHP_EOL,$names);
for($i=0;$i<count($names);$i++){
    $temp = explode(' ',$names[$i]);
    // Separating first and last names
    $guest_first[$i] = $temp[0];
    $guest_last[$i] = $temp[1];
}
print_r($guest_first); // Array ( [0] => Jane [1] => John [2] => Ehye )
print_r($guest_last); // Array ( [0] => Doe [1] => Doe [2] => Sukk )
```

Comment: Thank you Verma, I'll give this a shot.